# Should I chain a buffered stream to an input stream or use the URL class when loading a soundbank as an embedded resource?

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I have written a program which loads in a soundbank and can be compressed as a JAR file with the soundbank file embedded in and accessed from the JAR.

To clarify, the lines of code below belong to a method which is used to set up a MIDI Sequencer. The requirement here is to load a soundbank file (other than the default MIDI soundbank) using the Soundbank class which can then be used to set up the MIDI synthesiser.

When looking into methods for loading the soundbank file as an embedded resource I came across two different approaches which appear to work (I've omitted the try / catch statements for clarity's sake):

**Approach 1**

```
 InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/soundbank.sf2");
 InputStream sb = new BufferedInputStream(is);
```

**Approach 2**

```
 URL sb = getClass().getResource("/soundbank.sf2");
```

---

After milling through the source code it appears that both methods are very similar, and they are probably fairly indistinguishable at this level. I found Oracle's [Location-Independent Access to Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) explanation to be quite useful.

---

Since posting I have found that I can also use the following approach (although it appears to be fairly redundant to write it this way as the first thing **Approach 1** does is try out this approach. Might save a nanosecond or two I guess...):

```
 InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/soundbank.sf2");
 InputStream sb = new BufferedInputStream(is);
```

It's also clear that this approach is not suitable for use with web based applications, but that doesn't apply to the situation outlined in this question.

Comment: The first approach gives you a stream, the second gives you a URL.  These are different.  What are you doing with them?  If passing to a library, the library will take the URL and open a stream, so in the end, not much has changed.   Except perhaps proper closing of the streams.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I've edited the question to clarify what it is I'm doing with the soundbank. I understand they are different but I don't really have a clear understanding of the significance of the difference as they both appear to achieve the same ends in this case.

Comment: I expect in both cases you are doing something like `midi.load(sb)`.  In the former, that would call `load(InputStream is)`.  In the latter, it would call `load(URL url) { try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) { load(is); }}`.  If you look at the source code for `getResourceAsStream()`, you’ll see it calls `getResource().openStream()`.  So in the end, you have the same chain of calls.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Great, thanks for the advice. I've had a dip into the source code and the word labyrinthine comes to mind! My overall impression though is that the URL approach is a bit of a hack and is probably a little less efficient than Approach 1. Saying that, I have no hard analysis to back that up. In case you were interested, the next call is `soundbank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(sb);` where `soundbank` is a reference to a `Soundbank` object. I had noticed `getSoundbank(sb)` takes URL or InputStream object references as an argument before posting so that part made sense to me when I posted.

Comment: After reading further I haven't a clue which approach would be more efficient, but it does seem like there's very little in it, that is if there's any difference at all.

Comment: Yup!  As I said, you end up with the same underlying calls either way.  The only real difference is you get to ensure the stream is wrapped in a `BufferedInputStream` with approach 1, where approach 2, you’re relying on the MidiSystem library authors to have used efficient input code.